# How to place 3D tiles in unity tilemap to the height (z axis)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, tiles, tile

I have some tile map with 3D meshes on it, I would like to place the meshes on each other without creating new tile maps (On Z axis). How to do that?

Here are the settings of all the components of this system:

[![Properties of the gird][1]][1]

[![Properties of the tilemap][2]][2]

[![Properties of the pallete][3]][3]

I tried to play with axis and orientation but it didn't work.
I wanted to change my Transparency sort axis in camera settings but I didn't find it, I'm working on unity's version 2021.3.20f1 maybe because of that.